# How can I host n number of static sites on S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, host

I want to have the ability to host any number of websites on AWS s3, ideally in the same bucket. Can I do this with Route53, or does that need distinct buckets for each site? what's the best service to use for this?

Comment: You need one bucket for each site. You probably want it that way too. There is no reason to put everything in one bucket.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, because I'm pretty sure theres an upper limit to the number of buckets I can create (1000 I think?)

Comment: The issue is mostly around how the site is referenced. What is your desired URL pattern for accessing a static site? Will each of them have a different domain name? Or can you use `example.com/site1/index.html`? If each of them requires a different domain name, then they would each need a separate bucket. See: [Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

Comment: From [Bucket restrictions and limitations - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/BucketRestrictions.html): "By default, you can create up to 100 buckets in each of your AWS accounts. If you need additional buckets, you can increase your account bucket limit to a maximum of 1,000 buckets by submitting a service limit increase."

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from having multiple accounts to circumvent the 1000 bucket limit, we do exactly that.

Comment: John - completely different domain name yes. could I not use a cloudfront/lambda edge setup for this?